# Why route.params is giving me undefined inside the component when using react navigation in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Please don't mark this question as duplicate. The others answers doesn't save this one.

I am now trying to get the route.params inside the react native component and render it on the screen

I am now trying it on snack.

The thing is when I console.log `route.params` at the start of the component the `console.log` is showing me the params.

But when I console.log `route.params.mathNumber` the console.log is showing me ***undefined***.

here is the pic

[image: console picture]

Since I make sure I am passing the correct param `mathNumber` what seen to be the problem here?

Here is the code I am working with

```
function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      <Button
        title="Go to Details"
        onPress={() =>
          navigation.navigate('Details', {
            params: {
              mathNumber: Math.floor(Math.random() * 999),
            },
          })
        }
      />
    </View>
  );
}

function DetailsScreen({ navigation, route }) {
  const { mathNumber } = route.params;
  console.log(route.params)
  console.log(route.params.mathNumber);
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Details Screen {mathNumber} here</Text>
      <Button
        title="Go to Details... again"
        onPress={() =>
          navigation.push('Details', {
            params: {
              mathNumber: Math.floor(Math.random() * 999),
            },
          })
        }
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

For ez test case
you can go to this snack link

[Link To Snack](https://snack.expo.io/?platform=android&name=&dependencies=%40expo%2Fvector-icons%40*%2C%40react-native-community%2Fmasked-view%40*%2C%40react-navigation%2Fbottom-tabs%40%5E5.8.0%2C%40react-navigation%2Fdrawer%40%5E5.9.0%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-bottom-tabs%40%5E5.2.16%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-top-tabs%40%5E5.2.16%2C%40react-navigation%2Fnative%40%5E5.7.3%2C%40react-navigation%2Fstack%40%5E5.9.0%2Creact-native-paper%40%5E4.0.1%2Creact-native-reanimated%40*%2Creact-native-safe-area-context%40*%2Creact-native-gesture-handler%40*%2Creact-native-screens%40*%2Creact-native-tab-view%40%5E2.15.1&hideQueryParams=true&sourceUrl=https%3A%2F%2Freactnavigation.org%2Fexamples%2F5.x%2Fmultiple-push.js)

and replace the 2 component with my code

As you can see I am trying to render different `mathNumber` when I navigate through different detail screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the way you are adding params you will get mathNumber like this

```
const  mathNumber  = route.params?.params.mathNumber;
```

or you can do

```
 onPress={() =>
          navigation.navigate('Details', {
              mathNumber: Math.floor(Math.random() * 999),
          })
        }
```